# I accidentally plugged my USB mouse into my eSata port... it works?

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse, thinkpad, esata

I'm on a Thinkpad T510 and I accidentally plugged my Razor USB mouse into the eSata port not realizing my error because it has been working fine this whole time. Does this seem a little odd?

Comment: Never heard of such a thing! But how awesome!

Comment: It's a combo port...

Comment: I did this by accident on my Dell Latitude laptop and it fritzed out the screen; I had to reboot.  Now I put clear tape over the esata port.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

It sounds like you have a USB/eSATA combo port AKA eSATAp.  Which enables you to use either the USB or the eSATA on that particular port.

[image]

Picture taken from: *[techarena's forum](http://forums.techarena.in/hardware-peripherals/1179180.htm)*.

> eSATAp is also known as Power over eSATA or eSATA/USB Combo. eSATAp port combines the strength of both eSATA (high speed) and USB (compatibility) into a single port. **eSATAp devices are now capable of being self powered.** On a desktop workstation, eSATAp port can supply 12 V to power up a 3.5" hard disk drive (HDD) or a 5.25" DVD-RW without needing separate power source as compared to eSATA and USB 2. On a notebook eSATAp port can supply 5 V to power up a 2.5" HDD/SSD as compared to eSATA. Many notebooks are now equipped with this combo port. A list of notebooks with this new port is available [here](http://pcsg3.com/esatap.shtml).
>   **eSATAp can be implemented in all machines with a spare SATA port.** These machines include PC notebooks, desktops, Apple Mac Pro, and Linux or Unix servers. This makes eSATAp an easy, economical, cross platform solution for external storage.

[Serial ATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) (Wikipedia).

Comment: Damn, that's cool. I couldn't believe the OP's question until I saw your answer.

Comment: You're right, it's the Power eSATA. Good info!

Comment: *Welcome... to the world of tomorrow!*

Comment: Yes! Welcome to the world of tomorrow... (looks at USB-C ports... welp.)