# USB-device plugged into an eSATA

Tags: usb, esata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I accidentally plugged my USB mouse into my eSata port… it works?](https://superuser.com/questions/183543/i-accidentally-plugged-my-usb-mouse-into-my-esata-port-it-works)

My father bought a nice USB-gadget for me and wanted to demonstrate it to me. So he plugged it in as I wasn't at home. Unfortunately he has plugged it into the eSATA-jack and not into the USB-jack. I didn't see it for quite a while and the gadget and the notebook was running fine for hours (although the [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB)-gadget was plugged into [eSATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESATA#eSATA)).

Does anybody know if this can be done without being potentionally harmful?

(I'm very astonished that it hasn't done harm and even more surprised as it has worked. Pressing plugs into jacks which shouldn't be put there feels wrong to me.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that most of the newer eSATA jacks also act as USB jacks. On my Dell E6400 that is the case. The shape of the opening is slightly different to accommodate both.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESATA/USB

[image]

Comment: +1 Excellent answer, I did not even know they existed. That would explain why it worked in the first place as I was scratching my head on that one too, at first. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESATA/USB#SATA-IO (search combo).

Comment: Whoa!  Never seen one of those before.

Comment: Yup, the Dells have had this for a couple of years now.